# Unable to print username text in master page after login. Error: Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#, asp.net

After attempting to login, I am unable to capture my username and paste it onto the master page. An error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Member'.'Why is this so? I want to be able to print the username onto the master page on the label. But I get caught with the: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Member'.'

This is my HomePage.Master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            lblUser.Text = ((Member)Session["user"]).Username;
            lbtnLogin.Text = "Logout";
        }
        else
        {
            lblUser.Text = "";
            lbtnLogin.Text = "Login";
        }
    }
```

This is my LoginForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Allows login to be stored to session*/
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandText = "select * from Participant where participant_username=@participant_username and participant_password=@participant_password";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@participant_username", tbxUserName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@participant_password", tbxPassword.Text);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            rd.Read();
            Session["user"] = tbxUserName.Text;
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "Invalid username or password.";

        }
    }
```

I understood the removal of the Member cast, however another part of my code causes an error:

```
    if (Session["cart"] == null)
    {
        ShoppingCart s = new ShoppingCart();
        s.Member = (Member)Session["user"];

        Session["cart"] = s;
    }
    ShoppingCart sc = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
    sc.Seminar = a;
    sc.schid = b;
    sc.Seminar.Speaker = c;


    Response.Redirect("ShoppingCartForm.aspx");
```

This part of a code is in my shopping cart form, where if the shopping cart session is empty, I initialize a new shopping cart with the member. s.Member = (Member)Session["user"]; threw an error.

Comment: Why do you cast that `UserName` to `Member` anyway? It's a string already, you want to use it as a string, and you get an error message when you cast it to `Member`. So really, why insist?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
lblUser.Text = ((Member)Session["user"]).Username;
```

To:

```
lblUser.Text = (string)Session["user"];
```

This is because on the button press you're setting the session value to a string value from the `tbxUserName.Text`:

```
 Session["user"] = tbxUserName.Text;
```

Comment: I tried doing that, however in my another page: I get a: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Member'.' THis page is my List seminar page. It consists of:        


        if (Session["cart"] == null)
              {
                  ShoppingCart s = new ShoppingCart();
                  s.Member = (Member)Session["user"];

                  Session["cart"] = s;
              }

Comment: Looks like you're mixing the value that you are storing in `Session["user"]` either store one value that is use across all your pages or store in another key - `Session["username"]` / `Session["memeber"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is why you make use of a wrong cast.

The `Session` keeps a collection of objects. The type of the objects of this collection is `System.Object`. This is the base type of all the objects in .NET. 
So you can store in `Session` any object type. Actually you store references to objects and you can retrieve them either by a name (as you do) or by a numberical index (`Session[0]`, `Session[1]`, etc.) However in read a property of an object, whose reference is stored in `Session` you have first to make a cast and then try to access this property. In your case as I can infer from the following line:

```
 Session["user"] = tbxUserName.Text;
```

the type of the object `user` you store in `Session` is a `string`. So by making the following cast:

```
 lblUser.Text = (string)Session["user"];
```

you would retrieve that you want.